Should the phrase 'beat that time' be replaced by 'surpassed the record'?
In an article on sporting achievements, the author has compared the performance of two sprinters, Jesse Owens and Usain Bolt [Ref : Burlington English (UK) lesson] :

In 1936, Owens set an astonishing new record when he ran 100 metres in 10.2 seconds. Usain Bolt beat that time in 2009, completing the distance in just 9.58 seconds. This may not seem like much, but when it comes to breaking records, every split-second counts.
After reading the article, I thought the Jesse Owens 1936 record was broken only in 2009. But when I searched the net I found that it was broken many times (more than 10 times).
Why does the author use the phrase 'beat that time ' when that record was already broken earlier?
Ref. Cambridge dictionary:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/surpassed
surpass
verb [ T ]   formal
to do or be better than:
His time for the 100 metres surpassed the previous world record by one hundredth of a second.
Can we replace 'beat the record' with 'surpassed the record' ?
Usain Bolt surpassed that time in 2009, completing the distance in just 9.58 seconds.


You are making it so we have to go and dredge up the research on this point. The fact is you know what beat the time means otherwise you could not have asked the question in terms of Usain Bolt. This kind of question belongs on a sports site not on ELL.

This site: https://sports.stackexchange.com/

Beating a time is not the same as beating a record.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on SE's Sports site, not this one.

It's just a badly written, badly researched article.  Bolt had already beaten Owens time by  running a 10.03 in 2007 (and possibly before that, although he'd specialised in 200m before then).  Moteover he broke the record in 2008 with a time of 9.72.  All this is irrelevant to the answer (as given below) but suggests that this was not well written.

@MichaelHarvey I never said it was and I could give a rat's derrière. This question is not about the English language.

Go to the Sports site. Please.

@Lambie: I think you're being hostile for the sake of it. As Micael points out, Beating a time is not the same as beating a record. But that's a fine distinction that would rarely be significant, and wouldn't necessarily be obvious to a non-Anglophone dealing with what I'd say is text of "questionable" quality. The OP's question is quite properly posted here, not on some sports forum, since the OP is only asking about the language, not the actual record-breaking times or their dates.

@FumbleFingers Did you read my first post? You don't seem to understand. He provided no research for his claim and given his level of English, I think he just wanted to "chastise" that text he found. He knows exactly what they both mean: Look at his last sentence. He could not have said that without knowing both expressions. So, he's not asking about language, he's questioning the truth of some online article.

@Lambie: I have no preconceptions about the OP's level of English. But the final question is Why does the author use the phrase 'beat that time ' when that record was already broken earlier? That seems like quite a reasonable thing to ask, because part of the answer is probably The cited text isn't very well written.

@FumbleFingers It's isn't a preconception. My comment is based on the facts of language as demonstrated in his question. Yes, the question is reasonable IN SPORTS, but he couldn't have asked it unless: He was asking about the sports thing and not a language thing. I see nothing wrong at all with the writing. It ain't Shakespeare but how much sports writing is? JamesK says it is badly written when he means: it contains inaccurate information. Not the same thing. There is not one language, style or semantic "mistake" in that text.

And, fyi, looking back over his question, I confirmed an impression I already had: his English level is very high and he seems to have been educated in English. I see no trace of another language anywhere.

@FumbleFingers : I feel you had assessed me correctly. I am non native and learnt (or still learning) English the hard way. I don't consider myself an expert and don't understand why Lambie think so. I posted this to check if there was any mistake in the text or I had understood incorrectly.

Well, I think @MichaelHarvey's comment nails it for me, but I'm a native speaker anyway, so that just means I think his comment goes straight to the heart of the confusion. And I'm in no doubt almost all of your confusion here is because the text you're citing is clumsily written (it's not because your English is weak! :) The very strong implication of Usain Bolt beat that time in 2009 is that Bolt was the first to beat Jesse Owens' record set in 1936. Your cited writer is obviously either ignorant, illiterate, or both.

@fumblefingers compared to show that Jesse Owens ran under different conditions in 1936 . However, Bolt performed under very different conditions. Modern racing tracks have a slightly bouncy, non-slip surface that enables runners to move as fast as is humanly possible. Owens, in contrast, ran on a simple dirt track that actually slowed him down. Film footage of Owens sprinting was analysed to find out how fast he would have run on a modern track. The results showed that he would have been less than a step behind Bolt and that's without  running shoes that Bolt was wearing

This comparison indicates that new records in athletics are not necessarily the result of changes in human ability. Rather, it is the conditions that have changed. New technologies and special sporting gear have revolutionised almost every sport and helped athletes push the limits of their potential.

@JamesMathai: I won't say it's completely untrue, but imho none of that really stands up. Poor thinking and writing! No such "footage analysis" is currently possible (though AI's might change that soon! :) And it's screamingly obvious that today the global population from which talent may be drawn is 3-4 times bigger than in Owens' day. A population on average much better fed, with better healthcare and far more "spare capacity" to engage in sports rather than food production. It would be astonishing if athletic records of all kinds hadn't been shattered repeatedly over the past century!

@Lambie :- It is a language question because the extract is taken from an English lesson of the reputed UK company - Burlington English.

@FumbleFingers .I do not question the article's legitimacy, even though I cannot locate the original publication. (It is a lesson from the UK co, Burlington English.
I found this in the internet which also claims that Jesse Owens and Usain Bolt were compared using technology.
'Biomechanical analysis of the speed of Owens' joints shows that had been running on the same surface as Bolt, he wouldn't have been 14 feet behind, he would have been within one stride," said Epstein.
https://www.usatoday.com/story/life/entertainthis/2016/02/18/lets-all-appreciate-how-fast-jesse-owens/80523426/

"Film footage of Owens sprinting was analyzed" Personally, I find this claim highly dubious. Maybe it's truly possible to analyze film of a runners stride and calculate how fast he could have run on some alternative surface. But I'd question how reliable such an analysis would be. Maybe if I saw the details I'd be impressed.

Has this been experimentally verified? I mean, if they said that we got a group of test subjects to run on one surface, we analyzed the film and predicted how fast they would run on a different surface, then we had them run on the other surface and our predictions proved accurate to within x%, I'd take it seriously. But if it's just, We just know in our heart of hearts that this is right, sorry, I'm not impressed.

@jay In the lesson they cited 4 points

Owens ran on dirt (cinder); surface which slowed him. Bolt ran on bouncy rubber surface. They used some technology to measure this (please check the link above. Now they don't make actual car models, but models on computer. So this shouldn't be so hard to believe)
Shoes used by Bolt.
Bolt had full time training while Owens had to work to pay his fees.
Bolt had a special cook and nutritious diet.
Not only racing,  25 records were broken in swimming ( 9 by Michael Phelps) at Beijing because of the swimming pool design


@JamesMathai And none of that is "science". That is carefully reasoned logic. It's valid to form the basis of a scientific theory. But until you perform actual experiments to prove that each of those things actually do produce such-and-such a difference, what you have is not "science" but philosophical speculation. It may be true. I'm not saying it isn't. But without experimental evidence, it's not science.

Oh, cars can be designed using computer models because the computer models have been validated by experiment to be accurate. If someone just said, "I think that an aluminum engine block can probably sustain engine temperatures of, oh, probably 90% of what a steal engine block can", that would be almost worthless. But if you conduct experiments, find the real number, and then plug that into your computer model, it's meaningful and useful. Likewise, if someone can say, We did experiments where we got the same people to run on ash and to run on spongy rubber, and they were able to run x% ...

faster on rubber, this would then be a solid experimental result that you could plug in to a computer model. But if someone says, I carefully analyzed the stride of people running on ash versus people running on rubber, and I think you could run x% faster on rubber ... that's speculation and not science.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@jay If they have to make people believe they have to conduct experiments.
Here it is :-
All of these things were actually put into a test that was run by the CBC in Canada. They got Olympic sprinter Andre De Grasse to run under similar conditions as Jesse Owens.  De Grasse was a bronze medalist at the 2016 Olympics in the 100m and has a personal best time of 9.9 seconds. Owens and De Grasse were both of similar height and weight.
https://everything-everywhere.com/jesse-owens-vs-usain-bolt-who-would-win/#:~:text=If%20their%20personal%20bests%20were,only%20it%20were%20that%20simple.

90% of the article you cite is speculation. Read the final paragraph: "I THINK Jesse Owens ... if he had modern conditions. IT IS POSSIBLE he could have ..." etc. All of which may be true, but it's all speculation. The one solid experiment is related only briefly, and to me it's the only really important thing the writer has to say. It's important evidence that his claim is true, but one experiment with one test subject should not be taken too expansively.

The writer talks at length about how Owens didn't have access to the training that Bolt had. Would he have done better if he could have devoted full time to training and had the various other advantages? I'm sure he could. But how much difference would it all make? Hard to say. I'm sure that if I could have devoted full time to practice and training at running I would be a much better runner than I am. Could I have reached Olympic levels? It's impossible to say.

@jay The article also tells about Roger Bannister, a doctor who did the morning shift, and won the marathon gold medal. I found many sites discussing the same thing. But my question is about the language and the confusion it created.

Yes, this discussion was a complete tangent.

To "beat" a result means to do better in some competition. It doesn't necessarily mean to set a world record. It is quite appropriate to say "Al beat Bob in the race" without Al setting any sort of record. It just means, in this particular race, between Al and Bob, Al came out ahead.
If you're trying to make some comment about these runners or sports records or whatever, that's not a language question but a sports question.

It is a doubt about the language used in an article, which incidentally is an article about sports.

Hi, Jay, are you familiar with the southern expression: Don't git it on ya? :)

I'm not convinced the wording of this answer is any clearer than the (sub-standard?) original text being queried. To "beat" a result means to do better in some competition implies both the winning and the losing times were achieved in the same competition. Which is often the case - but not here, where the "beating" time was achieved many decades after the "beaten" time first established a new record.

@jay It is a language question because the extract is taken from an English lesson of the reputed UK company - Burlington English.

@FumbleFingers To "beat" an opponent can mean that you won a direct competition. But it is common to talk about "beating so-and-so's time" or "beating so-and-so's batting average". I don't think there's anything unusual about such usage.

There's no need to tell me! I know that, and you know that. The problem is the exact cited example is poorly written and/or misleading to a reader who's not intimately familiar with English and / or not aware of the "ground truth" (that Owens' record was in fact beaten by several others before Bolt). No matter how good your English, if you don't know that fact, you'd never guess it from the cited phrasing!

Can we use the term, 'surpassed the record'  instead?

@JamesMathai If what's going on is that A set a record and then B did better than that, then yes, you could say "surpassed the record". If A didn't set any record but you just want to say that B did better than A, "B beat A's time" or "B beat A" is correct while "surpassed the record" would not be correct because there is no record under discussion.

@jay  think you explained well. Thank you I understood.
